# How to use the authenticated user's jwt token in an http request to an external service in Symfony 4.4?

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, openid-connect

I'm working with a PHP/Symfony 4.4 Backend api which authenticates users via jwt tokens created by an external identity service. lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle is used to validate tokens. I need to send an http request to an external service route with the user's jwt token to get some necessary data because the route returns the data depending the `sub` field in the jwt token. I tried getting the raw jwt token using `TokenStorageInterface` (`tokenStorage->getToken()->$rawToken`) but the property is protected.

Here is a preview of the object returned by `tokenStorage->getToken()->$rawToken`:

object(Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Authentication\Token\JWTUserToken)[638] protected 'rawToken' => string ''... (length=1476) protected 'providerKey' => string 'api' (length=3) private 'user' (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken)...

Comment: What do you see if you dump(tokenStorage->getToken())?

Comment: object(Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Authentication\Token\JWTUserToken)[638]
      protected 'rawToken' => string '<token>'... (length=1476)
      protected 'providerKey' => string 'api' (length=3)
      private 'user' (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken)...

Comment: So, and dump(tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser())?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please explain how your problem is related to [tag:rest], or remove that tag

Comment: dump(tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()) returns the user entity from the database, the service stores and updates the list of users from the identity server.

Comment: You probably have to inject JWTTokenManagerInterface too. https://symfony.com/bundles/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/current/9-access-authenticated-jwt-token.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get the encoded token string from

```
\Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\TokenExtractor\TokenExtractorInterface
```

Watch in your lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml, if you have token extractors specified.
Here is a configuration for 2 token extractors. One to extract from authorization-header und another to extract from cookie:

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
  ...
  token_extractors:
    authorization_header:
      enabled: true
      prefix: Bearer
      name: Authorization
    cookie:
      enabled: true
      name: 'TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME'
```

If so, you can use the service

```
lexik_jwt_authentication.extractor.chain_extractor
```

from your service-container to get the raw token.

**BUT!** this service is private, so you have either to inject it via services.yaml into your object or, if using autowiring, write a method within your controller class or the like and mark it as required:

```
/**
 * @required
 */
public function setTokenExtractor(TokenExtractorInterface $tokenExtractor)
{
    $this->tokenExtractor = $tokenExtractor;
}
```

You won't retrieve it by containers get() method!

Finally call the extract method on TokenExtractorInterface

```
$rawToken = $this->tokenExtractor->extract(<instance of current request>);
```